# Decoding binary heading value

Tags: c#, decoding

[image]

I am trying to decode the magnetic heading that is contained in a 10bit field. I am not sure how the above instructions are interpreted. What i did is just took the 10 bits and convert them to decimal like this

```
int magneticheading = Convert.ToInt32(olotoMEbinary.Substring(14, 10), 2);
```

But then i checked that 259degrees only need 9bits to be expressed in binary (100000011). I am confused about what does a most significant bit of 180 degrees mean and a lsb of 360/1 024 .

For example if i receive the following 10bits 0100001010 how are they converted to degrees according to the above instructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using floating-point math, multiply by 360 and divide by 1024.

Comment: It's a 10-bit counter (1024 total values) representing degrees from 0 up to but not including 360.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions the question references are missing, but Stephen Cleary's method appears to fit the two data points provided.  It may help to think of it as a unit conversion from 1024 divisions of a circle to 360.